# How to create sideways longtable where each cell contains a long paragraph?

Tags: equations, longtable, sidewaystable, blindtext, book-class

I need my table to be as detailed below:

1. Using `longtable` environment (multiple pages).
2. The table is `sidewaystable`.
3. Each cell can fit very long paragraph like when using `\blindtext[2]` and continues to the next page. (*If it's not possible, then just ignore this point*)
4. The table has only one head on the first page, but not on the next page.
5. The head part of the table has vertical line and its alignment is centered vertically and horizontally.
6. The body part of the table has vertical line and its alignment is top-left.
7. I can add the chapter as the title above the table.
8. I can add `\begin{align*}` for writing equation on both the head part and the body part.

I know this is too much for one question, but sorry I can't find the templates or site that discussing about these. I mean, even if I can find 1 of those requirements by myself, I can't combine it with another requirements and usually I will get an error. That's the point of my question, so, my table will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbB9C.png). (The image description is another table, but can help you to understand my question).

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[ margin=1cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
    

%\chapter*{MY LONGTABLE by ABCDEFG} (PLEASE INCLUDE THIS CHAPTER)
    
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{| c | L{4cm} | L{5cm} | L{5cm} | L{4cm} | L{4cm} |}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
        \makecell{$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)$} & \makecell{Identified \\ Goals/Issues}  & \makecell{The consumer’s strengths \\ to address these issues.} & \makecell{Consumer and Nursing \\ Interventions} & \makecell{Person/s \\ Responsible} & \makecell{Timeframe}\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        1 & 
%       \begin{align*}    (PLEASE INCLUDE THIS EQUATION)
%       x^2 &= x+2x+1\\   (PLEASE INCLUDE THIS EQUATION)
%       x^2 &= 3x+1\\     (PLEASE INCLUDE THIS EQUATION)
%       x^2-3x-1 &= 0     (PLEASE INCLUDE THIS EQUATION)
%       \end{align*}      (PLEASE INCLUDE THIS EQUATION)
        \blindtext[4] & \blindtext[4]  & \blindtext[4]  & \blindtext[4]  & \blindtext[4]  \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
    
    %\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, paracol in landscape?  It can handle equations and break in the middle of a paragraph.  The head could either be before the paracol or using column -1.

Comment: @JohnKormylo actually i've edited landscape to a4paper. Sorry.

Comment: `longtablr` can  break only between rows, not inside rows. Do you really need so long text in table cells? Who will read this. Better is write this as `description` list.

Comment: @Zarko actually this requirement is for my thesis report. It's called research matrix. And it must be in a table form. Each cell describing about problems, methods, and bla bla, so yes the text will so long.

Comment: Hm, do you know, how long is thesis of Albert Einstein :-). Power of your thesis should be to write this matrix on less than one page ...with other words, you cant put elephant in a lady suitcase. A way is consider  @JohnKormylo comment.

Comment: @Zarko ok, i'll try to fit it in one page. So, i've changed the `\blindtext[4]` to `\lipsum[2]`. And still, i can't add the chapter title above the table. And when i use column -1 it's getting many errors. Please help me. Let's say the third requirement is removed. So as you said before it's possible.

Comment: Here is my output. Weird isn't it? I wan't the chapter title and the table in one page. Even if i removed the dummy text and using shorter text, the table still on the next page after the title. Here is the preview link https://ibb.co/84hNdNq